# Data type is changing from { "+" } to { " - " } in NodeJs

Tags: typescript

```
app.put('/orders/update/:orderID', async (req, res) => {
    const orderID = req.params.orderID;
    const quantity  = req.body.quantity;

    // Fetch the existing order to get the productID and previous quantity
    const getOrderQuery = 'SELECT "productID", "quantity","cost" FROM orders WHERE "orderID" = $1';
    db.query(getOrderQuery, [orderID], async (getOrderErr, getOrderResult) => {
        if (getOrderErr) {
            return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error inside server...' + getOrderErr });
        }

        // Check if the order with the given orderID exists
        if (getOrderResult.rows.length === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Order not found' });
        }

        const { productID, quantity: previousQuantity,cost} = getOrderResult.rows[0];

        // Calculate the difference between the new quantity and the previous quantity
        const quantityDifference = quantity - previousQuantity;

        if (quantityDifference > 0) {
            // If the new quantity is greater, check if the extra quantity is available for purchase
            try {
                const purchaseResponse = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/inventory/purchase', {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        productID,
                        "quantity": quantityDifference, // Calculate the extra quantity to purchase
                    }),
                });

                const purchaseResult = await purchaseResponse.json();

                if (purchaseResult.success) {
                    // Extra purchase was successful, update the order with the new quantity and cost
                    const updateOrderQuery = 'UPDATE orders SET quantity=$1, cost=cost + $2 WHERE "orderID" = $3';
                    db.query(updateOrderQuery, [quantity, purchaseResult.cost, orderID], async (updateOrderErr, updateOrderResult) => {
                        if (updateOrderErr) {
                            return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error inside server...' + updateOrderErr });
                        }
                        return res.json({ message: 'Order updated successfully' });
                    });
                } else {
                    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Extra purchase was not successful' });
                }
            } catch (error) {
                return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error making request to /inventory/purchase' });
            }
        } else if (quantityDifference < 0) {
            // If the new quantity is lower, update the product quantity using the API
            const updateProductResponse = await fetch(`http://localhost:9000/inventory/update/productQuantity/${productID}`, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "quantity": -quantityDifference, // Calculate the extra quantity to add to the product
                }),
            });


            const updateProductResult = await updateProductResponse.json();
            const unitPrice = updateProductResult.unitPrice; // Access the unitPrice from the response

            if (updateProductResponse.status !== 200) {
                return res.status(500).json({message: 'Error updating product quantity'});
            }

            // Update the order with the new quantity and adjusted cost
            const adjustedCost = cost - (quantityDifference * unitPrice); // Adjust the cost
            console.log("adjusted cost is: "+ adjustedCost)
            const updateOrderQuery = 'UPDATE orders SET quantity=$1, cost=$2 WHERE "orderID" = $3';
            db.query(updateOrderQuery, [quantity, adjustedCost, orderID], async (updateOrderErr, updateOrderResult) => {
                if (updateOrderErr) {
                    return res.status(500).json({message: 'Error inside server...' + updateOrderErr});
                }
                return res.json({message: 'Order updated successfully'});
            });
        }

    });
});
```

In this code

```
const adjustedCost = cost - (quantityDifference * unitPrice);
```

Types of the variables are "cost"(any),"quantityDifference"(number) and "unitPrice"(any). As this code when I use {"-"} the type of "adjustedCost" in number. But whet I use {"+"} the typr of adjustedCost in any. Tell me Why?

What is  the  reason for happening it and I need to replace "-" with "+"

Answer (score 0):

Because `+` could also be for instance a string concatenation but `-` and `*` can only be a numeric operation. Thus,

```
 (quantityDifference * unitPrice)
```

is always a number. But TS cannot deduce the result of `any + number` to something else than `any`. On the other hand `any - number` can only be a number. It may be `NaN` (if `cost` is really not a number), but still `typeof NaN === 'number'`